# How can my script know when I'm in a virtual console vs. an xterm?

Tags: shell, command-line, terminal, xterm

A few of my scripts (keymap changing, public key adding) need to act differently when in a virtual console vs. in an xterm.  What's the real code for

```
#!/bin/ksh
if [[ in_a_virtual_console ]]; then
...
else
...
fi
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds to me like you want to check whether or not there is a X server to connect to.

Something like:

```
if [ -n "$DISPLAY" ]; then
  : X
else
  : no X
fi
```

Comment: I've never been in the position of having three perfect answers on stackexchange.

Answer (score 10):

If you meant to distinguish interactive from noninteractive shells, use `test`'s inbuilt support for detecting it (not sure if ksh has it, but the binary from coreutils supports it too):

```
test -t 0 # will return 0 for interactive shells
```

If you really meant whether you're on a tty/pty/pts or something else, parse the output from `tty`:

```
$ tty # konsole
/dev/pts/4
$ tty # virtual terminal
/dev/tty2
```

Comment: I've never been in the position of having three perfect answers on stackexchange.

Answer (score 8):

This will depend on the operating system. For Linux, you could do this:

```
#!/bin/ksh

if [ "$TERM" == "linux" ]; then
  echo "I'm in a virtual console"
else
  echo "I'm not in a virtual console"
fi
```

This, of course, assumes that you have not changed the `TERM` environment variable yourself, which is automatically set to `linux` only when you log into a virtual console (under Ubuntu it is set to `xterm` in console applications, but this may vary between OSes). Check the contents of TERM in the various applications you're using, and set as appropriate.

Comment: I've never been in the position of having three perfect answers on stackexchange.